# How to install JQuery UI 1.8.3 and JQuery 1.5.1

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have to install JQuery UI 1.8.3 and JQuery 1.5.1 in same ASP.NET MVC 4 project. When I map JQuery files like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.18.js"></script>
```

It works properly, but when I deploy it JQuery 1.5.1 doesn't work because 1.8.3 is already installed.

When I try with this:

```
<script src='<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.18.js") %>'></script>
<script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.js") %>"></script>
```

It doesn't work.

Can somebody suggest how to diferent JQuery versions in same ASP.NET MVC project?

Thanks

Comment: your second load for jquery came after jquery ui. jquery ui runs on jquery thus jquery must be called first .. ps you are using only 1 jquery (v1.5.1) the other is jquery-ui and it is a different library that runs on jquery

Comment: I'd never reccommend to use two different version of jquery. These will blow your mind.

Comment: As @SnakeEyes already mentioned but still to reiterate,never use multiple versions of jQuery or jQuery UI or any js file for that matter,it will cause random fluctuations in behaviour and even in JQuery there are huge variations between the older and newer versions.It is always recommended to use the latest version as they seem to have fixed bugs which may still be present in the older versions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your ordering is wrong, it should be:

```
<script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.js") %>"></script>
<script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.18.js") %>"></script>
```

jquery Ui depends on base jquery, so it should be included first, otherwise you will have errors.